# Django Rest - "serializer.data" is empty dict() even though "serializer" has data with details

Tags: django, rest, serialization

I was trying to implement password change based on some recommendations on stackoverflow but something was not working which is really weird for me. After troubleshooting I got idea data the my view is not working. Changing serializer actions to print I see data "serializer.data" is result "{}" even though "print(serializer)" give result.

serializers.py

```
class ChangePasswordSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    old_password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True, required=True)
    new_password1 = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=128, write_only=True, required=True
    )
    new_password2 = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=128, write_only=True, required=True
    )

    def validate_old_password(self, value):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        if not user.check_password(value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {
                    "old_passowrd": _(
                        "Your old password was entered incorrectly. Please enter it again."
                    )
                }
            )
        return value

    def validate(self, data):
        if data["new_password1"] != data["new_password2"]:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"new_password2": _("The two password fields didn't match.")}
            )
        validate_password(data["new_password1"], self.context["request"].user)
        return super().validate(data)
```

views.py

```
class ChangePassword(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ChangePasswordSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            # user.set_password(serializer.data.get("new_password1"))
            # user.save()
            print(serializer.data)
            return Response("Success", status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

[image: Print(serializer.data)]

[image: Print(serializer)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'write_only=True' fields are not included when serializing the representation. If you want to debug you can print `request.data` or remove parameter write_only or set it False.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/

Comment: Thanks, a lot, I got it. One more question, please, Does token associated with my user gets deleted in password change or I have to add function for it?

Comment: If you are using default token authentication, you'll need to generate a new token manually.

Comment: I am using Simple JWT

Comment: Got it then you can use the function below.
`from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken` 
`RefreshToken.for_user(request.user)`

Comment: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creating_tokens_manually.html